# VBA - Cancelling Dialog Box Run-time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am attempting to have my end sub when I click cancel.  However, I am getting a Run-Time Error when I do so.

[image: RTE 1004]

I am just trying to close the dialog box which I did with an `Else: Exit Sub` statement.  However, it still shows the Run-Time Error, while it should just exit sub.

Comment: You do not show us enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: If you find an answer, please post it as an answer rather than as an edit to your question.  you can still do it now and even mark it as accepted.

Comment: @TobyAllen - I did that initially but Paul disagreed with that approach.  So I am a bit conflicted as to which approach is best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple fix of just adding an ErrorHandler like so:

```
Public Sub Run_Split()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Call Private Subs

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "User Cancelled Program", vbCritical
End Sub
```

Thank you to everyone that has helped me on this site in the past, your help as allowed me to be somewhat self taught in VBA and I was able to solve this without asking for assistance.

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes.